# How to determine battery related info of iOS device programmatically?

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm implementing iOS application in which I want to check battery information, like battery status, current battery level, is charging plugged in or not, etc. I did all this, but I want more info about battery like battery temperature, battery health, battery scale, battery technology. All this information is available in android, but can anyone help me to have all these info in iOS?

Comment: Did you find any success on getting this information? @Trup

Comment: Any updates on this? I know that the battery monitoring unit has a thermometer attached to the battery (allowing the device to display the overheating screen), but is there any way to get access to this without jailbreaking the device?

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
         [[UIDevice currentDevice] setBatteryMonitoringEnabled:YES];
        float batteryLevel = [[UIDevice currentDevice] batteryLevel];

        //This will give you the battery between 0.0 (empty) and 1.0 (100% charged)
       //If you want it as a percentage, you can do this:

      batteryLevel *= 100;
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I did this, now I want to determine battery temperature, battery health, battery scale, battery technology. Can u help me?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/BatteryStatus/Listings/Classes_RootViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008812-Classes_RootViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_6

Comment: Again thanks, but this is also giving me same info like status and current battery level. But these thing are done. I want battery temperature, battery health, battery scale, battery technology.

Comment: @Trup: Are you able to get the battery health, battery scale?